# Sign in with curl

Tags: php, session, curl

I tried but I cannot sign in with below code. After execution i show the login page again. Can anybody help me?

```
$tmp_fname = tempnam("/tmp", "COOKIE");

 $curl_handle = curl_init ("https://accessmanager.thy.com/amserver/UI/Login?goto=http%3A%2F%2Fwww2.thy.com%3A80%2Fuhkm");

 curl_setopt ($curl_handle, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $tmp_fname);
 curl_setopt ($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

 $post_array = array('gx_charset' => 'UTF-8','encoded' => 'true', 'goto' => 'aHR0cDovL3d3dzIudGh5LmNvbTo4MC91aGtt','IDToken1' => 'XXXXXXXX', 'IDToken2' => 'XXXXXXXX');

 curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_array);

 $output = curl_exec ($curl_handle);

 $curl_handle = curl_init ("https://accessmanager.thy.com/amserver/UI/Login");
 curl_setopt ($curl_handle, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $tmp_fname);
 curl_setopt ($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);


 $output = curl_exec ($curl_handle);

 echo $output;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow redirects too:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

Comment: CURLOPT_POST  is missing too.